# HTML / JS Controlling Poster Images and Video

Tags: javascript, ios

Being new at web dev and to this very informative stackoverflow site, I      am at a disadvantage to you Pro’s. The answers here are just simply GREAT

For anyone who would offer Im in need of some direction on my HTML / .js project. It contains a play button, 1poster start image, 1 video, 1 poster end image.

The project:

1 – click the play button overlaying poster start image (red background)
2 – poster start image closes
3 – video player opens / plays video / video player closes
4 – poster end image opens (blue background)

The issue Im trying to solve is – Immediately following the closing of  the video player, for a millisecond, the poster start image (red background) appears then disappears prior to the desired poster end image appearing.

Here is the `enter code here` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexLifeson/usueb9t0/)

Thank You All